# How to define a function pointer in the current context?

Tags: c, linked-list, function-pointers

Hey I am a bit confused as to how I would define a function pointer if I am given the following defs:

```
struct menu_item
{
    char name[ITEM_NAME_LEN+1];
    BOOLEAN (*func)(struct vm*);

};
```

The way I have defined what initial variables that menu_item contains using the following using the function menu_init. This function is suppose to define what each member of the array of menu items.

```
void menu_init(struct menu_item * menu)
{
    strcpy(menu[0].name, "\t1. Display Items");
    menu[0].func = (*void)&print_list(struct vm_node node); //print list is suppose to print the entire linked list past to the function print_list. Though i am unsure if this is correct. 

    strcpy(menu[1].name,"\t2. Purchase Items");
    strcpy(menu[2].name,"\t3. Save and Exit");
    strcpy(menu[3].name, "\t4. Add Item");
    strcpy(menu[4].name,"\t5. Remove Item");
    strcpy(menu[5].name,"\t6. Display Coins");
    strcpy(menu[6].name, "\t7. Reset Stock");
    strcpy(menu[7].name,"\t8. Reset Coins");
    strcpy(menu[8].name,"\t9. Abort Program");

  /* The UNUSED() function is designed to prevent warnings while your 
     * code is only partially complete. Delete this function call once 
     * you are using vm in your own code */
}
```

The declaration of print_list is as follows.

```
void print_list(struct vm_node  *root);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what are you having problems with.

Comment: Just syntax. Basically im not exactly sure how i would declare it so that when i use menu->func it will call the print_list function and print the entire list.

Comment: note that the `print_list` function and the function pointer member in `struct menu_item` have different parameter lists and return types? Other than that all you have to do is assign the function to the member `func` in your structure.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is an example of creating and assigning (in the same line...) a function pointer

```
int g(int y){return y;}

int main()
{
    int (*f)(int x) = &g; // initializing f with the address of g. f is a pointer to a function that returns int, and has 1 int parameter
    printf("%d",f(1)); // calling g, using the pointer f
    return 0;
}
```

Now, function pointers can be abused, so `f = g` instead of `f = &g` will also work, and there are a few more ways to achieve the same result.

About your code, you could have assigned, like I did in the example above, `menu[0].func = print_list;` if `print_list` was a Boolean returning function. Instead, you defined it as void returning function.

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is wrong.

The easiest fix is to get rid of the cast, by changing the function to have the proper type to match the function pointer:

```
BOOLEAN print_list(struct vm_node *root);
```

Then you can just do:

```
menu[0].func = print_list;
```

Note that this makes more sense, since the code that calls through the `func` function pointer *will* expect a `BOOLEAN` return value, so forcing it to use and call a mis-matched function by casting is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single `struct menu_item` variable

```
struct menu_item m ;
m.func = you_function_name ;
```

That is the syntax, which in your case would be:

```
void menu_init(struct menu_item * menu)
{
    strcpy(menu[0].name, "\t1. Display Items");
    menu[0].func = print_list;
    ....
```

And you call it like any other function:

```
menu[0].func( node) ;
```